# How do I use the bitmap debug visualizer in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

I'm attempting to use the bitmap visualizer in Visual Studio 2010, but when I bring up the quick watch window I don't see the magnifying glass described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zayyhzts.aspx). I set the app to full trust under the Security tab of the project settings but it didn't help. Has anybody successfully used the bitmap debug visualizer?

Comment: Oops..looks like maybe there isn't one included for bitmaps by default! Lame..

Answer (score 7):

Oops. Don't know why I thought this was included in Visual Studio 2010 but there is a 3rd party version [here](http://imagedebugvisualizer.codeplex.com/).

Comment: You can mark your answer as a "Question answer" in order to clean things up :) The community will thank you!

Comment: please do. Your question and answer helped me today.